# nginx on VirtualBox Ubuntu guest serves stale content

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualbox

I don't know if this is a problem with Ubuntu, VirtualBox or nginx.

I am running nginx on Ubuntu, which is a VirtualBox guest on Windows 7.  A Windows 7 folder is mounted as a auto-mount, read-only Shared Folder in VirtualBox.  Ubuntu sees the folder as /media/sf_jsource

Now, if I edit a file in that folder on Windows 7, a shell command (cat) on Ubuntu sees the new content.  That would seem to imply that VirtualBox and Ubuntu are picking up the new changes just fine.

However, the nginx server running on Ubuntu keeps serving the stale content.  That suggested that the problem was with nginx caching files.  I googled around and saw a couple of entries (from 2010, 2011) to disable the nginx cache.  However, I have not enabled any cache in the nginx config, and I don't see any /var/cache/nginx or /opt/cache/nginx directory to purge.

Now, the funny thing is that restarting nginx doesn't fix the problem.  I have to restart the Ubuntu guest for nginx to see the new content, which doesn't make sense since cat in Ubuntu was seeing the changes anyway before reboot.

Pretty much everything (nginx, Ubuntu, VirualBox) is the latest version as of early 2012.

Comment: I ran into this problem running Vagrant on OSX. As mentioned by @BenitoCiaro turning off `sendfile` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Facts:**

1. If you have not enabled caching in nginx, then nginx will not serve cached content.
2. If you restart nginx, any cached content is discarded in any case.

**Conclusion:**
Caching happens at many levels in the request cycle starting from your browser itself. Since the facts indicate that the caching is not by Nginx, you need to look into other possible cache locations starting with your browser.

Comment: It's a Nginx related issue + permissions. I have the similar problem, I am using Apache2 now ;-( No idea why btw.