# CSS stylesheet not updated in browser with DJango+Apache+Firefox on VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest

Tags: css, django, apache, firefox, virtualbox

I am having a problem with css stylesheets for a Django app that I am working on using a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 14.04. Everything appears to work fine, but when I change the contents of a stylesheet, the Firefox Style Inspector shows that the correct stylesheet is being used, but the changes are not there.

I have researched this online and have cleared the firefox cache multiple times, have installed an add-on that provides a button to clear the cache to make this easier, and have set firefox not to remember any history, but even if I close the browser and restart Apache, it still shows that it is using the old version of the stylesheet, even though it no longer exists.  Even if I shut the VM down and restart it the problem persists.

There must be a cached copy of the stylesheet somewhere, but I cannot figure out where it is, or how to force the use of the current version.

I did find a reference to something similar with nginx ([nginx on VirtualBox Ubuntu guest serves stale content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866106/nginx-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-serves-stale-content)) but it didn't shed any light on my situation.

There are no apparent errors showing in any of the developer tools windows and the app is otherwise working exactly as intended.

If anyone can help with this I would be truly grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the [`manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) command to copy CSS stylesheet into the web directory.

Comment: Do I need to do that after every change to a stylesheet?

Comment: Yes.  Every time you change the static file on the **production** server you need to run `collectstatic`.  Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks.  I had misunderstood how the static files were handled when I read the documentation originally, but I get it now.